# Atribuir função a button gerado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extensão

Pessoal meu problema é um pouco difícil para eu explicar. Tenho esses `buttons` que são adicionados toda vez quando é clicado no "+" e quando clica em algum desses `button` eles removem a `div` pai (`.list-group-item`).

A questão é que eu só consigo atribuir essa função para esses botões direto no elemento html (`onclick="removeField("+amntFileds+")"`) mas eu queria algo como:

```
document.querySelector(".remove-button").onclick=function(){...}
```

Infelizmente não consigo fazer isso pelo fato de que os botões são adicionados dinamicamente, e antes de adicioná-los, eles ainda não existem retornando o erro do seletor que não o encontra.
Estou tentando usar este código em uma extensão para o *Chrome*, e não pode utilizar código inline...

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

**JS:**

```
var amntFileds = 1;
var superObj = document.querySelector(".list-group");
var btnAdd = document.querySelector(".add-button");

btnAdd.onclick = function(){
   Element.prototype.setAttributes = function(attrs){
      for (var index in attrs){
         if ((index == 'styles' || index == 'style') && typeof attrs[index] == 'object'){
            for (var prop in attrs[index]){
               this.style[prop] = attrs[index][prop];
            }
         }else if (index == 'html'){
            this.innerHTML = attrs[index]
         }else{
            this.setAttribute(index, attrs[index]);
         }
      }
   };

   //Criando o elementos;
   var subObj = document.createElement("a");
   var inputRemove = document.createElement("button");

   //----------------Setando atributos dinamicamente-----------------\\
   //Definindo atributos ao subObj(div list-group-item):
   subObj.setAttributes({
      "id" : "sub-field"+amntFileds,
      "class" : "list-group-item"
   });

   //Definindo atributos ao inputRemove(Botão de exclusão de comandos)
   inputRemove.setAttributes({
      "type" : "button",
      "class" : "remove-button",
      "html" : "&#10008;",
      //"onclick" : "removeField("+amntFileds+")"
   });
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------\\

   //Inserindo o elementos no subObj(list-group-item):
   subObj.appendChild(inputRemove);
   superObj.appendChild(subObj);
   amntFileds++;
}

function removeField(id){

   //Recebendo id de campo clicado
   var subObj = document.querySelector("#sub-field"+id); 

   //Removendo o DIV com id específico do nó-pai:
   var removed = superObj.removeChild(subObj);        

   //Decrementando campo adicionado em 1;
   amntFileds--;
   console.log("Campo "+amntFileds+" removido!");
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list-group">
</div>
<br><button type="button" class="add-button">&#10010;</button><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="action.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pq vc gostaria dessa forma se o onclick funciona?

Comment: não é recomendado não usar função inline?

Comment: Entendi sua pergunta.

Comment: Não há problema nenhum em usar onclick.. seu código está funcionando perfeitamente... querer usar `querySelector` iria complicar.

Comment: Sugestão: deixe o onclick mesmo, é até melhor, na minha opinião... apaga a sua pergunta pq não vai ser útil qualquer resolução além disso

Comment: estou tentando usar este codigo em uma extensão para o chorme, e parece que não pode utilizar codigo inline...
`Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Comment: Vc disse "parece"... se funcionar, ignore esses avisos... pelo que vi, não parece ser sobre o onclick

Comment: mas não funciona

Comment: Então é melhor colocar esses detalhes na pergunta.... senão as pessoas vão perder tempo tentando solucionar uma coisa que funciona normalmente no navegador.

Comment: A sua questão está meio confusa e faltam detalhes. Atribuir o evento de click por código nada afeta em relação ao facto de o botão só ser adicionado depois. Se ele só é adicionado depois, só no momento em que ele é adicionado é que você atribui o click com `addEventListener()`. Já para não falar que criar o html com `innerHTML` é muito mais fácil, especialmente se utilizar interpolação de strings.

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais fácil de trabalhar com eventos em elementos criados dinamicamnte é usando jQuery veja:

```
$('body').on('click', '.uma-classe-qualquer', function(evt) {
    // aqui é possível pegar qualquer informação do elemento (id, data, etc...)
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
})
```

Já se o uso de jQuery não for viável em seu projeto o jeito é usar [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) nos elementos que você adicionar dinamicamente exemplo:

```
let inputRemove = document.createElement("button")
// adicione um "ouvinte"
inputRemove.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    // por exemplo para pegar o id:
    alert(this.id)
}, false)
```

Note que você pode especificar uma função como referencia ao invés de declarar uma:

```
// awesome function
function coolFunc(evt) {
    alert(this.id)
}
// handler
inputRemove.addEventListener('click', coolFunc, false)
```

Comment: O "downvoter" poderia sugerir o que esta errado em minha resposta, isso ajudaria a corrigir e a encontrar uma solução a questão #FIKADICA